# Connecting client (on VirtualBox) and server (on localhost) using CORBA - org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:

Tags: java, c++, virtualbox, corba

Im working now on simple gui appllication in Java/C++ and CORBA. I want my client on VirtualBox connect to server on localhost. When I have a simple app, like a calc I wrote about earlier its just fine. But when it comes to run client which needs some args witch javas `-cp` option, Im getting errors. **(Theres no such problem when I have both client and server on localhost!)** Im using Win XP on VirtualBox and Ubuntu on localhost.

My errors:

```
WARNING: "IOP00100007: (BAD_PARAM) string_to_object conversion failed due to bad
 scheme name"
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.soBadSchemeName(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.soBadSchemeName(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.ORBInitRefResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(Unknown
Source)
        at ClientConnection.connect(ClientConnection.java:57)
        at Client.main(Client.java:295)

Exception in thread "main" org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 7
 completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.soBadSchemeName(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.soBadSchemeName(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.ORBInitRefResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(Unknown
Source)
        at ClientConnection.connect(ClientConnection.java:57)
        at Client.main(Client.java:295)
make[1]: *** [run] Error 1
```

ClientConnection.java:57 is a line `objRef = clientORB.resolve_initial_references("NameService");`
Client.java:295  is a line:  `ClientConnection.connect(args);`

A `connect` method is just an ordinary client-connection corba code.

I ran my example:

1) 
`C:\Temp\Client>java -cp .:../Dir1:../Dir2 Client -ORBInitRef NameService
=corbaloc::192.168.56.1:2809/NameService
Error: Could not find or load main class Client` so its even didnt run at all ..

2) with the help of a Makefile:

```
HOST = 192.168.56.1
PORT = 2809
NAMESERVICE = NameService

run:
    java -cp .:../Dir1:../Dir2 Client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::$(HOST):$(PORT)/$(NAMESERVICE)
```

by typing `make run` and then I got those error I posted earlier. Whats wrong? I mean, a simple code works fine but gui version doesnt want to ... is there a problem with `-cp` option? I cant change my apps' dir tree.

Comment: just a guess, but on Windows, the items in the classpath should be separated by semicolons, not colons. It's colons on Linux.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek : I changed it with same result ... :( `Could not find or load main class Clinet`

Comment: did you mis-spell it as 'Clinet' as in the message that you quoted, or did you just mis-type that in your comment? Either way, it's got to be an error in setting your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally see two problems you have.

1. the classpath thing. Do you hava a file named `Client.class` in `.` or `Dir1` or `Dir2`. If not, look for it and add it's dir to the classpath. If it is in, please provide more information
2. The CORBA thing; I would like to see your `Orb.init();` call. Everything else looks good.